# Как отказаться от автоматической установки рекомендуемых пакетов?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt-get

Команда apt-get install кроме запрошенных пакетов по-умолчанию так же устанавливает не только необходимые (описанные как required), но и рекомендуемые (recommended) пакеты. Как отказаться от установки последних?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Параметр для установки только необходимых пакетов

```
--no-install-recommends
```

Для того чтобы не прописывать параметр каждый раз, можно отключить установку рекомендуемых пакетов, для этого необходимо сделать файл

```
# nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10norecommends
```

с содержимым

```
APT::Install-Recommends "0";
APT::Install-Suggests "0";
```